# Task Manager - Processes & Users Tab empty

Tags: windows-10, process, reboot, task-manager

I have Windows 10 1903 and it's some time that if I open the Task Manager, the Processes and Users tab are empty.

[image: screenshot]

After trying to reboot the system, I found out that immediately after the reboot, the processes and users are showing correctly, but after a while they stop to show up.

Also, if I reboot the system after the issue showed up, I receive the message "Someone else is still using this pc"

I tried to use the commands `qusers` and `qwinsta` to see who is the user connected, but I receive the error `Error 5: Access denied`.

I've also tried what is suggested [here](https://www.kapilarya.com/fix-someone-else-is-still-using-this-pc-in-windows-10), but to no avail.

Comment: Have you checked *thoroughly* for malware? Also, try Sysinternals' *Process Explorer*, which should show all proceses. Run it as Administrator, if it does not Se https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

Comment: I have bitdefender installed and I've done a scan with malwarebytes. Do you have other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: 1. Scan from a rescue CD or USB. 2. Look at Process Explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you are an italian like me and I also had this exact problem.

In the end I found that the problem was a program needed for the CNS (Tessera Sanitaria), in particular the one called IDProtect (it's only for the ACTALIS type of CNS, [see this link for more information](https://sistemats1.sanita.finanze.it/portale/elenco-driver-cittadini-modalita-accesso)).

Remember to close the task manager, shutdown the program and then reopen the task manager to see the changes.

Comment: That is it, I would never have find out this

Comment: I tried to search for contacts of the developer of the program to advice on the issue but I was not able to find anything. By chance, do you have any idea on this?

Comment: Same problem with ACTALIS software

Comment: So maybe ACTALIS is the owner?

Comment: The process to kill in my case is "IDProtect Monitor.exe". The path of the file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Athena\IDProtect Client\Utils\IDProtect Monitor.exe".
Thank you NaNNy!

Answer (score 0):

just focus the list and hit F5

Answer (score 0):

same problem from Italy here,
this time in task-manager/startup there was

"framework for CNS smartcard x64 bit"

once disabled, problem gone!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).